# How to make an installed application to run in background?

Tags: applications, background-process

Let's say I record some video or audio and then I switch to other application, the first one goes in the background and stops working for that time (while the second in the foreground). How would I make an application to continue recording until it' completely closed?

(Android 10).

Comment: You, the user, can't. Developer of the app can.

Comment: This really depends on how the applications are coded, there's no way for the user to modify that logic. Otherwise, this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241919). It might be a better idea if you explain what you're really trying to do so that the community might be able to give alternative solutions.

Comment: @Andrew T. there are applications that record something (video/audio), if switch to the other app they'll stop record, so they should always work even if in background.